# How to add Mapcluster in Google Map Api using iPhone webView?

Tags: google-maps

i want to add map cluster in my UIWebView using google map api but i dont want that whole map cluster library along with my Xcode project so is there any alternative to map cluster available with small library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this v3 implementation of google map cluster

http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/markerclusterer/docs/reference.html